# Best price or exact match, How market order would be matched when all are limit orders?

Tags: trading, stock-exchanges, limit-order

Suppose, there is a Limit sell order with
Limit Price : 21,
Qty   : 21000

then another new Limit sell order placed as below
Limit Price : 20,
Qty   : 200

Now if a new limit buy order placed as below,
Limit price : 21,
Qty : 400

I agree, buy Limit order should match with Lowest sell order available. But If buy limit order has exact match available with Limit sell order, then with whom buy order should match? i.e Which order should get high profit buy order or sell order in case there is a exact match order?

Comment: The answer is that your buy order would get matched with 200 shares for 20 and 200 shares for 21, for an average price of 20.5

Comment: But if there is exact match available for buy order then why should buy order get high priority to make profit than sell order?

Comment: Please see the duplicate question. It has answers which should answer your questions